# get previous element tag name

Tags: javascript, jquery

with the html like this:

```
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="tot-1">
<span class="input-group-addon btn btn-default addQR">+</span>
```

How can I get of the input element when I click on the button?

I have tried this:

```
$("addQR").click(function(){
var caunter = $(this).closest("input");
var nameclosest = getElementsByName(caunter);
```

});

but it doesn't work.  Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a period in the selector of the button, and you should be using `.prev()` not `.closest()`. You already know the tag name `input`, so I wonder why you would be trying to get it; you're probably trying to get the `name` attribute:

```
$(".addQR").click(function(){
  var caunter = $(this).prev("input"),
      nameclosest = caunter.attr('name');
});
```

```js
    $(".addQR").click(function(){
      var caunter = $(this).prev("input"),
          nameclosest = caunter.attr('name');
      alert( nameclosest );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="tot-1">
<span class="input-group-addon btn btn-default addQR">+</span>
```